# Through what way can we be allowed to use the nonfree module in commercial use

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that the nonfree module is patented by someone,I'd like to know how can we be allowed to use this in our commercial operation, how about the fees ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82881/through-what-way-can-we-be-allowed-to-use-the-nonfree-module-in-commercial-use/) by [sunshine0707](https://answers.ros.org/users/7036/sunshine0707/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ask that 'someone' what he charges for commercial operation.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2